# Liquid syntax error: Tag was not properly terminated with regexp: /\%\}/

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, liquid

I have a an `if` condition in my liquid template like this

```
Username: {{user.email}}
{% if extras['password_to_be_sent'] %}
Password: {{extras['password_to_be_sent']}}
{% endif %}
Trial expiration: {{user.trial_expiration}}
```

However this is generating a line break when the if condition does not evaluate to `true`

so the above generated output like this

```
Username: Abc

Trail Expiration: 2019-11-10
```

I want to remove the additional line break when the `if` condition does not evaluate to `true`

i tried adding `-` as suggested here https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/

so updated code to

```
Username: {{user.email}}
{%- if extras['password_to_be_sent'] -%}
Password: {{extras['password_to_be_sent']}}
{%- endif -%}
Trial expiration: {{user.trial_expiration}}
```

but this is giving an exception `Liquid::SyntaxError (Liquid syntax error: Tag '{%- if extras['password_to_be_sent'] -%}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\%\}/)`

Additionally, I am saving the template code in database, if that helps.

Any help in this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there! What version of Liquid is your app using? I see you've also tagged Ruby on Rails, so if your Rails app is consuming a version of Liquid before 4.0.0, you won't be able to use the whitespace control tags. Those were added in Liquid 4.0.0.

Comment: hi @AdamHollett, thanks for your reply. I was using the gem version 3.0.6 and i update it to 4.0.3 but now i am getting a error `undefined method liquid_methods` in my user.rb

Comment: hi @AdamHollett, thats was the issue, would you want to put this in a answer so if someone visits the post it would be helpfull, i can mark the answer as accepted, thanks

Comment: Done! thanks for getting back to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered above in a comment, but here it is again:

> I see you've also tagged Ruby on Rails — if your Rails app is consuming a version of Liquid earlier than 4.0.0, you won't be able to use the whitespace control tags. Those were added in Liquid 4.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to make sure `extras['password_to_be_sent']` doesn't return a truthy but empty string?  Maybe it should be:

```
Username: {{user.email}}
{%- if extras['password_to_be_sent'].present? -%}
Password: {{extras['password_to_be_sent']}}
{%- endif -%}
Trial expiration: {{user.trial_expiration}}
```

Comment: `.present?` is not valid Liquid. You can do something similar by comparing equality with the special `blank` keyword:

`{% if foo == blank %}
  This will only print if foo is not set or if it's an empty string
{% endif %}`

Answer (score 0):

When I change line 134 from

```
int dis[4][2]={{0,1},{0,-1},{1,0},{-1,0}};
```

to

```
int dis[4][2]={ {0,1},{0,-1},{1,0},{-1,0}};
```

It fixed !